# Is there a way to get some sort of SIM card Identifier on iPhone programmatically?

Tags: ios, core-telephony

Is there a **LEGAL** or **PUBLIC-API** way to obtain some sort of SIM card identifier programmatically, the only thing so far i found is that there is a `NSNotification` that occurs when SIM card is changed while app is in runtime, but that is not enough for me...

Is there some kind of public API in `CoreTelephony` that allows some kind of `UUID` get from SIM card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually **NO** you can retrieve operator code, country code, but not **ICCID**.

Answer (score 1):

The id you are looking for is `ICCID` (Integrated Circuit Card Identifier) and there is **no official api** to get that information from an iOS devise programatically, without the risk of getting rejected by app store.

You can check your own in iccid at `Settings -> General -> About -> ICCID`

Comment: Thanks, but that's not helping, i need some kind of SIM card UUID programmatically, not just to find out my own ICCID... Thx anyways

Comment: @mvukicevic there is no way to programatically find the ICCID without the risk of getting rejected. Even if you do want to use the private api the phone needs to be jail broken.